# Could not find method compile() for arguments

Tags: android

Error:(13, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Bible'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v7] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: please share you gradle file.

Answer (score 5):

It appears as if you have not added compile statement to your dependencies.

Try this-

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0"
}
```

This should go in the module's build.gradle file, not in the project's one.

Like this-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0"
}
```

Refer to [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for specifically saying it should go in the module's build.gradle. I kept trying to do this in my project one and it was causing all sorts of errors. Every other answer just kept saying to add it to my build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I just do InvalidateCaches 3 times and it works fine. I do that because it was working before I shut down my PC but when i start my pc again it showing this error,It means there is no error regarding code.
By the way thank you sir:).